# Different urls for YouTube api

Tags: youtube-api

I have links from youTube like:
http://www.youtube.com/sothebysrealty?x=us_showcase__

and

http://bit.ly/KQVFK0

and using the generated embed iframe code from the youtube site, it doesn't work. How can I use these urls instead of the normal youTube ID? Or is there another way to get an id from YouTube... I've looked at both "share" links and both of them have full urls like the above that don't contain the typical youTube id.

The snippet that works with regular ids:

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="360"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sjhO9gLO1Sk"
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen />
```

but using the above links do not.

Thanks-

Answer (score 0):

You're asking about using arbitrary URLs for the src= of an  tag to trigger the embedded player? That's not possible.

If you have a YouTube watch page URL for a specific video (not a bit.ly URL or a URL for a channel page, but a watch page URL) then you might find the oEmbed service useful for generating the appropriate embed tag: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2009/10/oembed-support.html

Comment: thanks, I had a YouTube dev show me the obvious..right-click on the actual vid and copy the url, pull the id!